# How to prevent autosize textarea from entering into Footer with Fixed/Z-Index footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to prevent textarea to enter into footer?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uqhh05en/

```
var coola = {
  init: function() {

 autosize(document.querySelectorAll('textarea'));

 $("textarea").keyup(function(e) {
    //Tried a hack for not autogrow below footer
    $('.footer').focus();
    $(this).focus();
  });

  } 
};
$(coola.init);
```

Plugin:     http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize

**Note**: No fixed Rows and Cols allowed to textarea.

**Note**: No Fixed height allowed. I want to resize and resize as text increases.

Answer (score 1):

The footer is over the content because it is `position: fixed`.  When the text area resizes automatically it will increase the size of the parent div too.  You can see the 'hiding' textarea by scrolling down.

I suggest adding some code that scrolls the screen down by the height of one line each time the resize is triggered for affected textareas.

Comment: It is good suggestion and i have implemented most of it. An issue still persists. Suppose i enter text with 50 - 60 rows and i take cursor to second row in textarea then again it scroll down up and down up and down up.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your issue... but I would include a check in the code to see if the screen is already scrolled all the way down, and only scroll more if that was the case.

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't really explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding-bottom:80px` to your main div. so that it have getting more space in bottom and your textarea not hide in footer.

```
<div style="width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-bottom:80px">
  <textarea id="text1"></textarea>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  <textarea id="text2"></textarea>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  </br>
  <textarea id="text3"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  I am a cool footer & I hide autosizing textareas behind me :p. <br>
  If you have guts then Comeon solve the issue
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing happens by doing this. It is still hiding